# syslog shows cronjob running

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have created a script to delete old files and put it in crontab to run every 2 mins. I can see that the syslog shows the cronjob running, but the files are not deleted. I can run the script manually, it runs without any errors. And I also used "sudo crontab -e" so as to give root permissions to the cronjob. Any ideas why the files are not deleted?

Crontab is as follows:

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/bash /mnt/md0/capture/delete_old_pcap.sh
02 00,12 * * * sh /usr/bin/nfexpire.sh
```

The script is as follows:

```
   #!/bin/bash

  ulimit -S -s 50000
  LIMIT=10
  NO=0
 #Get the number of files, that has `*.pcap` in its name, with last modified 

 NUMBER=$(find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" |wc -l)

 if [[ $NUMBER -gt $LIMIT ]]  #if number greater than limit
 then

 del=$(($NUMBER-$LIMIT))

 if [ "$del" -lt "$NO" ]
  then
  del=$(($del*-1))
 fi
FILES=$(find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" -print0 |$
rm -f ${FILES[@]}
#delete the originals

fi
```

Comment: Paths/environment variables/something else.... Show the crontab and relevant parts of the script if you can

Comment: you can redirect the output to a file and read it what's wrong

Comment: Most likely a problem with either relative paths and a different working directory, or permissions. However there is a question: what do you mean by: "And I also used "sudo crontab -e" so as to give root permissions to the cronjob."? `root` always has permission to all ressources on a unixoid system and that command does _not_ change the way cron works. It only means you _edit_ the crontab with root permissions. That has nothing to do with the execution!

Comment: @arkascha all I meant is I wanted the script to be run as root, so I used "sudo crontab -e" instead of just "crontab -e". :)

Comment: Yes, but you are wrong in that, this is not what you get by this. As said: that command switches your effective user id during the _editing_ of the crontab, not during its execution. So maybe I should ask: which crontab is that? Systemwide ? roots crontab? a users crontab?

Comment: `/mnt/md0/capture/delete*.sh` Will never work as you intend. e.g. if you have delete1.sh, delete2.sh, delete3.sh, it will call `delete1.sh delete2.sh delete3.sh`. Which is to say it call `delete1.sh` with arguments `delete2.sh` and `delete3.sh`

Comment: @BroSlow there is just one *.sh file in that folder.

Comment: Then that might work depending on how cron treats globs (avoid using it as answer says, just use the path you have), please show your script and what shell are you using when you say `it runs without erros`?

Comment: `sh` almost never equals `bash` on modern systems. Put `/bin/bash` in front of both cron commands and like answer says replace the `*` with the actual path.

Comment: I have updated the crontab, added the full path to the script, still it doesnt run

Comment: Maybe have it write all major variables to a log file and see what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

not sure it will solve your problem, but try:

```
*/2 * * * *  /bin/sh /mnt/md0/capture/delete*.sh
02 00,12 * * * /bin/sh /usr/bin/nfexpire.sh
```

i.e. give the *full* path to the shell when executing the commands.

I wildcards won't work as other scripts will be taken as arguments to the first script (good point @broslow). Instead, make a script that calls all the other scripts.

Something like the following:

script `/mnt/md0/capture/delete.sh`:

```
for f in delete.d/*.sh; do
    /bin/sh $f
done
```

with all scripts in `/mnt/md0/capture/delete.d/`

and then in your crontab:

```
*/2 * * * *  /bin/sh /mnt/md0/capture/delete.sh
```

Finally check your mail on your local computer, crontab sends output/reports on error by mail (i.e. type `mail` as the user running the crontab on the command line, i.e. as root in your case).

Comment: It won't even work in shell, it will assume all scripts after the first one are arguments to the first one.